# Singularities at roots of unity

Tags: complex-analysis, asymptotics, roots-of-unity

I want to construct a function $f$ with the following properties:
$f$ has a singularity at $z=1$, and for any $\zeta = e^{2\pi i\frac{a}{b}}$ with $(a,b)=1$, then
$$\lim\limits_{x\to1^-}\frac{f(\zeta x)}{f(x)}=\frac{1}{b}$$
E.g. $f(-x)/f(x)\to1/2, f(ix)/f(x)\to1/4$ etc...

I think it is likely such a function exists. For instance, let 
$$f(z)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^k}{1-z^k}$$
Then plotting the graph of $|(f(0.99\exp(2\pi ix))|$ for $0<x<1$ shows
[image]

Which appears linear! (linear by denominators, i.e. satisfying my conditions). Yet when I try to compute in individual cases, the ratios $\frac{f(\zeta x)}{f(x)}$, they do not seem to obey my conditions. (Or perhaps a software error. Maple has given me tantrums before). My question is, can anybody find a function satisfying my conditions? If not, any related information would be welcome.

I know deep down, that the growth rate of a function near roots of unity is wholey determined by the size of the denominator in 
$$\zeta = e^{2\pi i\frac{a}{b}}$$
But I would like to prove it! So any insights I would like to hear.

Comment: Is $x$ a complex number with zero "imaginary part," or is $x$ supposed to be the real part of a given complex number? You started with $z=1$ and then switched to $x$ as your variable so I am assuming you mean one of the two standard usages for $x$ in the context of complex variables.

Comment: Good point. $x$ is a complex number with nonzero imaginary part. I just prefer the letter x to z. I'll change all to z though.

Comment: OK. And $a$ and $b$ are integers with $b$ nonzero right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Your $f(x)$ has the form of a [Lambert series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_series), which have applications in analytic number theory. Perhaps something in that vein is what you want.

Comment: My f(x) was just a guess to show the people on MSE that there is reason to believe a function satisfying my conditions exists. I'm not interested in that particular f(x) though.